# Writing to a file in a C (Linux). What's wrong?

Tags: c, linux

2 days ago I've installed linux on my machine (1st time in my life :P) and now I'm tryin to write a char into a file. For some reason, it's not working... Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main (int xd, char *tab[]) {
    char *path1 = tab[1];
    int filee = open(path1, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT| O_TRUNC, 0777);
    write(filee, 'x', sizeof(char));
    close(filee);
    return 0;
}
```

What could be wrong in this little piece of code? I've checked and function 'write' returns -1, even though function 'open' creates the file when it doesnt exist.
Thanks.

Comment: Always check the return value of system calls (like `open` and `write`), and when they return -1, always log `errno`

Comment: If your program is successful, your `main` function should return `0` which, by convention, means "success". Any other value is interpreted as an error. This will not cause any problem in this case but it could (if you have a script that checks the return value of your program for example)

Comment: This is not your problem, but remember that in C, character constants like `x` have type `int`, not `char`, so your `sizeof` argument is wrong.

Comment: wow, I'm so used to see `argc` and `argv` that `xd` and `tab` got me puzzled for a few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write` takes a pointer to a memory buffer as the second argument, but you pass it an `int`

```
write(filee,'x',sizeof(char));
```

You should try something along the lines of

```
char c = 'x';
write(filee, &c, sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a character literal where `write()` expects a pointer to the data.

Try something like this:

```
const char data[] = { 'x' };

write(fille, data, sizeof data);
```

Also, you should check the return value of `open()` before relying on the file descriptor being valid.

When using API:s you're not familiar with, it's a good idea to [read the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write), and check the expected arguments against what you are using.

Also, you should enable more compiler warnings; this is something the compiler should have warned about, for sure.

Comment: Or you can also call `write` like this `write(filee, "x", sizeof(char))`